# How to get an accurate cost of deploying a bot solution?

Tags: azure, bots

Before moving from prototype to production phase, I want to calcualte accurate cost of production solution for getting better understanding of ROI.
i have built and deploy a bot which is based on enterprise bot template which is deployed using msbot deployment script which creates following services:Web App Bot, Azure Cosmos DB Account, App Service Plan, App Service, Storage Account, Application Insights, Cognitive Services (LUIS), App Service (QNA Host), Cognitive Services (QnA Maker), Search Service.

Azure portal allows to get pricing (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/), however, i am not sure whether i should include Cosmos DB as well as Storage Account? or is it a deployment script problem, 
Any pointers is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is a process i followed to get the correct cost of the production solution.

First, there are two ways you can build a bot (a) using VS studio template (VSIX) and build the bot and deploy using msbot script. (b) Create a bot on Azure and download the code and make changes.
(a) is a recommended option from MSFT.
With option (a) I have used msbot script to deploy the solution, that creates list of services in your Azure subscription. If you look closely, it creates Cosmos DB as well as Storage Account, Cosmos DB is mainly used for storing bot state and storage account is used for storing log and app insights, etc.

Also there are two app service are included, but if you look closely, both app service shares the same app service plan meaning one app service is used for both services, however, it depends on your need. 
Most of the services are allowed to scale-up, but azure search can not be scale-up, it must be re-created and re-configured.
Finally you need to include following services for calculating price using the azure price calculator:App Service,QnA Maker Service,LUIS Service,Cosmos DB, Storage Account, and Bot